# Minor grid in pgfplot not showing when specifying ticks manualy

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, grids, ticks

Firstly I would like a minor tick between every major tick in my `pgfplots` graph (and minor grids). I wrote `minor tick num=1` but it doesn't work. I am not using a logarithmic axis so it is unrelated to other questions.

Secondly, why is the tick label "1" missing for each axis? How do I get that to display?

[image: No minor ticks]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
footnotesize,
width=4in,
height=4in,
axis equal,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
grid=both,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xlabel={X},
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ylabel={Y},
minor tick num=1,
xtick={0,0.1,...,1},
ytick={0,0.1,...,1},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east,legend cell align=left,align=left,fill=white}
]

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: second one is easy : replace `1` with `1.01` or something larger than `1`. The first one I think doesn't work with explicit ticks. Or you need to supply also the `minor tick` key. I'm speculating though. Didn't check.

Comment: @percusse It does work with explicit ticks, try `xtick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0}`. Could it have something to with rounding, so that `0,0.1,...,1` doesn't create the exact sequence above?

Comment: @TorbjørnT Thanks I can confirm explicitly setting `xtick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0}` (and for yticks) solved both problems. Sounds like a bug if `0,0.1,...,1` doesn't work

Comment: If you want to call floating point roundoff errors (which I would think it is) a bug.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes probably. They don't work with nonuniform sequences. And that `0,...,1` syntax falls back to TikZ and uses TeX arithmetic. So probably that is the culprit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Setting all the ticks explicitly works:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
grid=both,
minor tick num=1,
xtick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
ytick={0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0},
]

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

I would think this is caused by roundoff-errors. You can see easily that `0,0.1,...,1` doesn't create the same sequence if numbers as above with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {0,0.1,...,1} {
 \x 
}
\end{document}
```

which outputs

[image]

The reason why the `1` tick was missing from both axes is clear. I'm not sure why the minor ticks are missing, it could be because the distances between the major ticks are not all equal, at least the manual states

> Minor ticks will be disabled if the major ticks don’t have the same distance and they are currently only
>   available for linear axes (not for logarithmic ones).

Comment: I think the minor ticks are missing because the error introduced by floating point means the distances 0 0.1 0.20001 are somewhat a little bit different, e.g. 0.1 and 0.100001

Comment: @MobiusPizza You can introduce integers and replace the labels with custom ones if that's a problem for your use case

Comment: @MobiusPizza My thought exactly, and also what I wrote in my edit.

Answer (score 7):

You could also try

```
xtick distance=.1,
ytick distance=.1,
```

instead of `xtick={0,0.1,...,1},ytick={0,0.1,...,1},`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
footnotesize,
width=4in,
height=4in,
axis equal,
scale only axis,
separate axis lines,
grid=both,
every outer x axis line/.append style={black},
every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
xlabel={X},
every outer y axis line/.append style={black},
every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{black}},
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
ylabel={Y},
minor tick num=1,
xtick distance=.1,% <- 
ytick distance=.1,% <-
axis background/.style={fill=white},
legend style={at={(0.97,0.03)},anchor=south east,legend cell align=left,align=left,fill=white}
]

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```