# Label axis in units of pi (or pi/2) and use minor tick num

Tags: pgfplots

Using `pgfplots`, I often want to label the horizontal axis major ticks in units of `pi` or `pi/2`, or `pi/3`. Is it possible to have such "trigonometric major ticks" use `minor tick num = <value>` to specify the number of minor ticks?

Currently my approach for "trigonometric major ticks" is to make a style `wholes` that specifies the `xtick=<integer multiples of pi>` and `xticklabels=<labels>`. I specify the ticks for a range -4*pi to +4*pi, and crop the graph as needed. I similarly have a style called `halves` for half-integer multiples of pi:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots} %This package also loads tikz

\pgfplotsset{
    % Global Styles
    axis lines = middle,
    xlabel = $x$,
    ylabel = $y$,
    no markers,
    samples=50,
    grid = both,
    trig format plots=rad,
    enlargelimits = false,
    axis line style = {line width=0.5pt},
    every axis plot/.append style={
        line width = 1.25pt,
        smooth,
        },
    % Label every pi
    halves/.style={
    xtick = {-12.5664, -10.9956, -9.42478, -7.85398, -6.28319, -4.71239, -3.14159, -1.5708, 0, 1.5708, 3.14159, 4.71239, 6.28319, 7.85398, 9.42478, 10.9956, 12.5664, 14.1372, 15.708, 17.2788, 18.8496, 20.4204, 21.9911, 23.5619, 25.1327},
    xticklabels = {$-4\pi$,$-\frac{7\pi}{2}$,$-3\pi$,$-\frac{5\pi}{2}$,$-2\pi$,$-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$-\pi$,$-\frac{\pi}{2}$,$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$,$2\pi$,$\frac{5\pi}{2}$,$3\pi$,$\frac{7\pi}{2}$,$4\pi$,$\frac{9\pi}{2}$,$5\pi$,$\frac{11\pi}{2}$,$6\pi$,$\frac{13\pi}{2}$,$7\pi$,$\frac{15\pi}{2}$,$8\pi$}
    },
    % Label every pi
    wholes/.style={
    xtick = {-12.5664, -9.42478, -6.28319, -3.14159, 0., 3.14159, 6.28319, 9.42478, 12.5664, 15.708, 18.8496, 21.9911, 25.1327},
    xticklabels = {$-4\pi$,$-3\pi$,$-2\pi$,$-\pi$,$0$,$\pi$,$2\pi$,$3\pi$,$4\pi$,$5\pi$,$6\pi$,$7\pi$,$8\pi$}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[wholes,domain=-pi:3*pi,ymin=-2,ymax=+4,minor tick num = 1]
    \addplot {1-2*cos(2*x)};
    \legend{$1-2\cos(2x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[halves,domain=-pi:pi,ymin=-2,ymax=+4,minor tick num = 1]
    \addplot[red] {2+0.5*sin(4*x)};
    \legend{$2+0.5\sin(4x)$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

**Problem:** I'm fairly happy with this solution, except `minor tick num=1` is not working on the x-axis. I think this is due to rounding errors. [Minor grid in pgfplot not showing when specifying ticks manualy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256323/minor-grid-in-pgfplot-not-showing-when-specifying-ticks-manualy)

Certainly I could specify the minor ticks manually. I really don't want to do this---I need to create many graphs like this, some times I want `minor tick num = 1`, sometimes I want `minor tick num = 3`.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I'm aware of that question (it's essentially the method I'm using now). The existing answers to that question do not allow for use of  `minor tick num =  <value>`

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer ...  We will see if this minor change satisfies not beeing a duplicate. Nontheless you have a working solution now which -- I think -- is the most important point, right? ;)

Comment: @Herbert Is this really a duplicate? I am (trying) to ask specifically about a method for generating trigonometric labels that allows for automatic minor ticks using `minor tick num`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using my solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292059/95441) you can easily add `minor tick num` to add as many minor ticks as you want.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        no markers,
        samples=50,
        trig format plots=rad,
        every axis plot/.append style={
            line width=1.25pt,
            smooth,
        },
    }
    % define precision of \pi
    % this is set here to the value of \pgfmathpi
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PI}{3.141592654}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-0.5*pi:1.5*pi,
            ymin=-1.5,
            ymax=+1.5,
            %
            % scale x axis values by \pi and
            % remove the corresponding label
            scaled x ticks={real:\PI},
            xtick scale label code/.code={},
            % in case you want to set an explicit tick distance
            xtick distance=\PI/2,
            % add code here for formatting the `xlabels'
            % I configured exceptions for \pm\pi where no number in front
            % of these are shown and for fractional values these should be
            % shown as fractions
            xticklabel={%
                \ifdim \tick pt = 1 pt
                    \strut$\pi$%
                \else\ifdim \tick pt = -1 pt
                    \strut$-\pi$%
                \else
                    % to avoid some mess with TeX precision, first
                    % round the \tick value to one digit after the comma
                    \pgfmathparse{round(10*\tick)/10}
                    % depending on whether the resulting number is an integer
                    % show it as integer only, otherwise use the style given
                    % in `xticklabel style'
                    \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{%
                        \strut$\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}\pi$%
                    }{%
                        \strut$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\pi$%
                    }
                \fi\fi
            },
            % set number plotting to frac style
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/frac,
                /pgf/number format/frac whole=false,
            },
            % add minor thicks
            minor tick num=1,
        ]
            \addplot {sin(2*x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

*Note: requires pgfplots 1.13+*

Comment: you might want to add `%` at the end of the lines to avoid whitespaces

Comment: @percusse, of course. Many thanks for the hint. I've adjusted the code.

Comment: @mrc, because now it gets off-topic I suggest continuing discussion in [this chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35525/discussion-between-mrc-and-stefan-pinnow)

Comment: The outcome of the chat was, that the remaining issues where due to an "non-up-to-date" PGFPlots version. The answer was edited accordingly.

Comment: When using `xtick distance=pi/4`, I got rounding errors that caused `pi` to be displayed as `1pi`. Moving the `\pgfmathparse{round(100*\tick)/100}` above the `if` and switching `\tick` to `\pgfmathresult` fixed this.