# pgfplots: minor y ticks not showing

Tags: pgfplots

below code does does not draw y minor ticks. I could specify them manually, but would prefer to have them drawn automatically by 'minor y tick num=1'. Also I do not understand why exactly they are not drawn in the example. Can anybody help?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    minor x tick num=1,
    minor y tick num=1,
    xtick={0,10,...,40},
    ytick={0,0.2,...,1},
%   minor ytick={0.1,0.3,...,0.9},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=40,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you joking?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get.

Comment: I would like to get minor y ticks at 0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7 and 0.9 without specifying manually

Comment: And if you try with `minor y tick num=0.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just providing the `minor x tick num=1` already gives the desired result. But I have given more possibilities in the code below how you can set `minor ytick`s. Have a look there.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.13
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        xmin=0,
        xmax=40,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1,
        grid=major,
        xtick={0,10,...,40},
        minor x tick num=1,
        % only setting the following key gives the desired result already
        minor y tick num=1,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % I think giving the `ytick's as abbreviated list causes some
%        % rounding problems and that is why the `minor ytick's are not drawn
%        % ...
%        ytick={0,0.2,...,1.0},
%        % ... this is supported by the fact when giving each entry also the
%        % `ytick's are drawn correctly
%        ytick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0},
%        % a simpler method to provide an equidistant tick position is using
%        % the following key which then also works fine with the
%        % `minor y tick num' key
%        ytick distance={0.2},
%        % and as you already have found out, this should be the last option
%        % to take into consideration
%        minor ytick={0.1,0.3,...,0.9},
    ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Dear Stefan, thank you very much for the detailed answer. I will use x/y tick distance from now on. Totally missed it in the manual. [Info on rounding errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256323/minor-grid-in-pgfplot-not-showing-when-specifying-ticks-manualy)

Comment: @user3795444, you are welcome. Besides accepting the answer you can also [upvote it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up), if you are satisfied with my answer.

Comment: @user3795444, at the rounding error: Great, that you have found an example proving it. I was just to lazy to search for it ;)